# About numbering in equation

Tags: equations, numbering, mathtools

I would like to have the equation numbering arranged in the picture. However, I cannot add the `\circ` only for equation (1.5). Could anyone please help me? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{c:/university study/photos}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\newtagform{Charles}{$($}{$)^{\circ}$}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\title{Properties of Gas}
\maketitle

\newpage
\stepcounter{section}
\setcounter{equation}{0}

\section*{Summary of Equation}

\begin{align}
p &= f(T,V,n) \label{eq:one}\\
p &= \frac{F}{A} \label{eq:two}\\
p &= \frac{\rho Agh}{A}\nonumber\\
&= \rho gh \label{eq:three}\\
T/K &= \theta/^\circ C +273.15 \label{eq:four}
\end{align}

\begin{flushleft}
Boyle's law
\end{flushleft}

\begin{align}
\usetagform{Charles}
pV &= constant,\text{ }at\text{ }constant\text{ }n, T
\end{align}

\begin{align}
p_j &= x_j \cdot p\\
x_j &= \frac{n_j}{n_{total}}\\
p_a + p_b +\cdots &= (x_A+x_B+\cdots) = p
\end{align}
\begin{flushleft}

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the way the equation is labelled (with the `\circ`) affect how it will be referenced? That is, if you label equation `(1.5)^\circ`, do you want the reference to that equation also to return `(1.5)^\circ`?

Answer (score 6):

The following code (a) employs the `mathtools` package to define a new equation tag form, called "Charles", and (b) creates two macros, named `\PlainTag` and `\CharlesTag`, that implement the default and "Charles" tag forms, respectively, for the current equation, irrespective of whether `\usetagform{Charles}` or `\usetagform{default}` is in effect. (One apparently cannot issue `\usetagform` directives *inside* an `align` group.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\newtagform{Charles}{$($}{$)^{\circ}$} % create a new 'global' tag form

% Create two "on the fly" tag forms:
\newcommand\PlainTag{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag*{(\theequation)}}
\newcommand\CharlesTag{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag*{(\theequation)$^{\circ}$}}

\begin{document}
\section{Summary of Equation}

\begin{align}
p &= f(T,V,n)     \\
p &= \frac{F}{A}  \\
p &= \frac{\rho Agh}{A} = \rho gh         \\
T/K &= \theta/^{\circ} \mathrm{C} +273.15 \CharlesTag % (override "plain" tag form
\end{align}

\usetagform{Charles} % switch to "Charles" tag form

\paragraph{Boyle's law}
\begin{align}
pV &= \text{constant at constant $n$, $T$} \\
p_j &= x_j \cdot p \PlainTag \\ % override 'Charles' tag form
x_j &= \frac{n_j}{n_{\mathrm{total}}} \PlainTag \\ % override 'Charles' tag form
p_a + p_b +\cdots &= (x_A+x_B+\cdots) = p % no override, hence use 'Charles' tag form
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I understand now. So, if I want to use `\usetagform{Charles}` for only 1 equation, that equation should occupy a separate `align`. Sorry for misunderstanding your answer in the last post.

Comment: @someone - Sure, you *can* do it that way. As you've noticed, `\usetagform{Charles}` cannot be undone mid-`align`. The `\CharlesTag` macro lets you override the default ("plain") tag form on a one-off basis. Incidentally, if a display math group consists of a single row, you really should be using `equation`, not `align`.